# Hacer que al activar un input[checkbox] este no sea desactivado al darle click de nuevo

Tags: checkbox

si puede ser en jquery o ajax la ayuda se los agradeceria la idea es que el usuario cuando le de click a ese checkbox no pueda destildarlo

Comment: No explicas qué has probado ni muestras código, y ni siquiera te molestas en explicar de qué lenguaje de programación estamos hablando... -1 y voto para cerrar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

podrias hacerlo asi

```
$(document).ready(function(){

     //verificamos si el input checkbox esta seleccionado
     if( $('.micheckbox').is(':checked') ) {

       $(this).attr("disabled",true);//si es asi lo desactivamos
}
```

}
})